# Cómo comprimir un zip a apk

Tags: android, apk, zip, studio

Tengo un APK descomprimido en un directorio que muestra las siguientes archivos y carpetas:
-assets
-lib
META-INF
-res
-Android Manifiest
-classes.dex
-resources.arsc

Y estoy haciendo una app en Android Studio que la vuelva a imprimir como APK.

El problema es el siguiente cuando comprimo el .zip y le cambió la extensión a .apk todo parece normal pero no sé instala poniendo un error de instalación. Aclararque antes de descomprimir el apk se instalaba y funcionaba perfectamente.

¿Debo usar una librería o seguir siertos parámetros? Que tengo que hacer para convertir el zip en apk

Comment: El APK del proyecto tienes que generarlo desde el propio Android Studio. En la opción Build-->Build Bundle/APK ó Build-->Generate signed Bundle/APK

Comment: Gracias aunque no es lo que busco lo que quiero es tener los archivos de la app descomprimida dentro de la app que estoy creando y que la misma los ponga en un directorio para trabajar con sus archivos y la comprima como .APK para poder instalarla estoy seguro q debe haber una manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitarías al cambiar el .zip a .apk es "alinear"  el zip.

> [ZIPALIGN](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign?hl=es)
>
> La herramienta de alineación de archivos zipalign permite optimizar en
> gran medida los archivos de aplicaciones para Android (APK). Tiene
> como objetivo garantizar que todos los datos sin comprimir comiencen
> con una alineación determinada en relación con el inicio del archivo.
> **Específicamente, hace que todos los datos sin comprimir dentro del
> APK, como imágenes o archivos sin formato, se alineen en límites de 4
> bytes.** De esta manera, puedes acceder a todas las partes directamente
> con mmap(), incluso si estas contienen datos binarios con
> restricciones de alineación. El beneficio es una reducción en la
> cantidad de RAM que se consume al ejecutar la aplicación.

Ejemplo de uso:

Para alinear el apk app.apk y guardarlo como myappok.apk que sería el .apk "alineado":

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> app.apk myappok.apk
```

Comment: Gracias soy principiante existe algún vídeo o tutorial en Youtube? zipalign es una variable?

Comment: es una utilería: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaeNCFIpM3I